# How do you update the default value for a field programmatically?

Tags: 7, entities

How do you update the default value for a field programmatically?  I know you can get the field instance info by calling [field_info_instance](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7), but how do you update that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`field_update_instance()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_instance/7) function is the standard method

> Updates an instance of a field.

You can take the array returned by `field_info_instance()`, make your changes, then pass it back to `field_update_instance()` and the changes will be saved.

Comment: I literally searched for an hour to find that function, assuming such a thing existed.  Apparently I just suck at searching today.  Must be a carryover from Monday.  Thanks Clive.

Comment: I remember this (and `field_update_field()`) taking me ages to find too. They seem to be named intuitively enough but my brain didn't seem to agree when searching!